# Copy images from imagefield

Tags: adobe, livecycle-designer

I currently have a pdf that contains imagefields.

The issue however is that we want to be able to copy the images users input into the pdf.

Is there a way to alter the imagefield or add a button to the form that will copy the image so it will be available for pasting?

I see that I can put a button on the page and via script access the value for ImageField1.value so I can set it. But how can I read it?

Answer (score 0):

you can access the image data by ".rawValue" attribute.
For example with a button and "click" event.

**FormCalc:** $.parent.sPic.rawValue = $.parent.dPic.rawValue

**JavScript:** xfa.resolveNode("sPic").rawValue = xfa.resolveNode("dPic").rawValue

with dPic being imagefield and sPic being image. This script will copy the image from imagefield into the image.

Comment: Will that copy the image to the clipboard for pasting to into an email or word?

Comment: No. As far as I know security since Acrobat 7.x(or even earlier) has shut the door on the clipboard.